# Remove duplicated firewall rules

Tags: nsis, windows-firewall

SimpleFC::AdvAddRule from [NSIS Simple Firewall Plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Firewall_Plugin) will add a duplicate rule if the exact rule already exists.

SimpleFC::AdvRemoveRule [name] will remove one entry, but not all of them.

What is a good way to remove duplicated firewall rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a loop and remove one by one until SimpleFC::AdvExistsRule is false if they all have the same name.

Comment: I was hoping for a one liner, such as AdvRemoveRules or a different plugin that handles duplicate adv rules. A loop will work though, thanks!